# Recognizing parameters and mapping to complex object

Tags: asp.net, api

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string empty;
  public int number;
  public AnotherClass Another;
}

public calss AnotherClass
{
  int number1;
  int number2;
}
```

**method**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("check")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromBody] MyClass request)
{
   //
   return new HttpResponseMessage() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK};
 }
```

Is it possible to map request where user send all parameters in body like this

```
{
 "empty":"test",
 "number":"5",
 "number1":"10",
 "number2":"15"
}
```

I don't want to change JSON part.

Comment: If you can't change the JSON, change your model - don't use a complex object in this situation. Otherwise you need to write a custom model binder which is overkill for such a simple situation.

Comment: It's not simple situation, I've just gave simple example of what I want to achieve. I know it's possible to change model or JSON, but I would prefer not to if possible

Comment: Your API endpoint models should really match the JSON, there's no reason to do it differently.

Comment: You are right and I know it, I just want to see if it can be different.

Comment: It can be, but you need to write complex model binders, one for each type, which is a huge amount of work.